# What is the history behind “raze” and “raise” (two words that sound the same but mean nearly opposite things)?

Tags: history, homophones

How did the English language come to have two words, “raze” and “raise” that mean practically opposite things, but sound the same?

*Merriam Webster definitions*

**Raze**: to destroy to the ground

**Raise**: to cause or help to rise to a standing position

I’m not aware of any other words in the English language that are this <s>unique</s> one-of-a-kind in that they have such contrasting meanings while being homophones.

As a side note I’m curious if this has ever led to disastrous results over verbal miscommunication.

Comment: Welcome to the idiosyncratically beautiful world of English.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I still remember the time as a child when I first came across the word raze. I was convinced it was a typo. :)

Comment: What did an etymology reference tell you?

Comment: Try "sanction" and "cleave" - they not only sound the same but they are even spelt the same, and each contains opposed meanings.

Comment: Note also "re-sign"/"resign" and "innumerable"/"enumerable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Raze**, from vulgar Latin *rasare*, meaning "scrape, erase." 15th or 16th century.

**Raise** is of Germanic origin, and three or four centuries older: *risan*.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/raise?s=t

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/raze?s=t

Comment: When there is a need to increase the height of furniture temporarily, often for people recovering from surgery or injury, they can be supplied with "chair raisers" which are blocks of wood with depressions drilled in the top to accommodate the legs of a chair. However if the client needs a shave they will use a "razor". The names of these items are derived from the unrelated verbs "raise" and "raze". Nothing strange at all.. it's similar to the case of the unrelated verbs "to bear" (meaning to carry) and "to bare" (used in 'to bare all' and meaning to reveal)